# flask_login sometimes mixes logins; I'm logged in as somebody else

Tags: python, session, cookies, flask, flask-login

I'm using the awesome [Flask framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/) to create a website in which I use [Flask-login](http://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for my user logins. This normally works fine, but sometimes I see strange issues with logins being mixed. We've got 3 flask dev-servers running on one machine (on different ports) and we're working in an office with about 10 people (with one shared ip). The problem is that sometimes one user is suddenly logged in as another user.

I can't really pinpoint when or under which circumstances this happens. But I also don't really know how I can debug it. Could the source of the evil be that we share an internet connection or is the problem that we run several flask dev-servers on one machine?

I don't know whether this also happens with people outside of our office (we're still in testing phase).

Can anybody give me some tips on how I can debug this?

Comment: Have you tried changing your `app.secret_key`? It's possible while testing and you're continually repopulating the database that the session user-id stored then attaches to what is now another user.id in the database.

Comment: @Doobeh - I tried that, but it doesn't work. Do you know if there is a way for me to end all sessions?

Comment: changing the secret_key invalidates all existing sessions, as it's the key that's used to sign them, so it's the same as ending all sessions.  Multiple servers with shared secret_keys might do something odd.  Paste up your `User` model and your `user_loader` decorated method to see if anything looks out of place there

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are using a web server which is caching (some of ) HTTP replies from Flask. These could include static media, generated media, PDFs, Office files.

A misconfigured front end web server may cache such a HTTP response containing media and the session cookie (`Cookies` header). After happily caching this response then the front end web server serves it to another user. The existing session cookie of this user gets overwritten with the session cookie from the cached HTTP response. Then, due to session switch, the user becomes the user whose HTTP response was cached.

Solutions

- Fix your session middleware
- Explicitly set no caching headers on the server side
- Configure your front end web server not to cache responses with cookies

[Further information in operationssecurity.org](http://operationssecurity.org/en/latest/web/index.html#no-caching-policy).

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate answer. The only server that I'm using at the moment is the Flask built-in development server. As far as I know (but I'm not sure) this dev-server doesn't cache things (because that would not be handy while developing. Do you have any other tips?